# Get errors in vendor.js in production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

error in ReactChildren.js:

[image: img1]

I am using React + Redux + Webpack + Babel. Get error in vendor.js. I tried to edit and commit, then got a new error.

[image: img2]

I updated my packages to the newest version except for eslint, built and run, got another error in lodash

Does anyone meet this problem before? Here is my web pack config file in production mode.

```
export default {


debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: {
    main: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './src/bootstrap'
    ],
    vendor: [
      'classnames',
      'immutable',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-redux',
      'react-router',
      'react-router-redux',
      'redux',
      'redux-actions',
      'redux-form',
      'redux-immutable',
      'redux-saga',
      'react-swipeable',
      'react-waypoint',
      'react-addons-css-transition-group'
    ],
  },
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    publicPath: `${config.STATIC_PREFIX}`,
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS), // Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', '[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new VendorChunkPlugin('vendor'),
    new AssetsPlugin({
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'assets.json',
      fullPath: false
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'views/index.pug',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true
      },
      inject: true,
      oneapm: config.oneapm,
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loaders: ['babel', 'eslint']
    }, {
      test: /\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|svg|eot|ttf)\??.*$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=1000&name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]'
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loaders: ['json']
    }, {
      test: /(\.css)$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?minimize!postcss')
    }, {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug'
    }]
  },
  postcss: [precss, calc, autoprefixer]
};
```

Comment: (I can't spot the difference in `a new error` - if possible, copy any error messages and paste into _block quotes_ (nesting a _code block_ may turn out the easiest way not to mess up formatting).)

Comment: Do not post pictures of test. Post the text.